# Как изменить размер шрифта текста checkbox?

Tags: html, checkbox

```css
.custom-control-label[type=text] {
   font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: normal;
}


<!-- media -->

.custom-control {
   font-family: 10px;
}
```

```html
</div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <div class="choice">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
            <label class="custom-control-label" id="label_text" for="Включить кабель в заказ">Включить кабель в заказ</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Не хочет меняться, гад. [image: Скрин страницы с чекбоксом]

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <div class="choice">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultUnchecked">
            <label class="custom-control-label" id="label_text" for="Включить кабель в заказ">Включить кабель в заказ</label>
            </div>
```

P.S: новичок, верстаю третьи сутки! ;D

Comment: А css какой прописан для этих элементов?

Comment: .custom-control {
   font-family: 10px;
}

Comment: Это прописано для media, но он все равно отображает оригинальный размер шрифта

Comment: .custom-control-label[type=text] {
   font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-weight: normal;
} (это стандартный, для норм экранов)

Comment: @Добавьте css в описании вопроса в специальный блок, для этого под вопросом есть кнопка `править`

Comment: @Inventor Исправила

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно для изменения размера шрифта используется свойство `font-size`, а не `font-family` =)

Comment: Упс :D Спасибо, сейчас исправлю)

Comment: Заработало, спасибо :D

Comment: Если ответ полезен, то около него можно нажать галочку и отметить его как решение проблемы)